# How many ways are there to distribute n objects into k boxes (each box can contain more than 2 objects and not more then 6 objects)??

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to distribute n objects into k boxes (each box can contain more then 2 objects and not more then 6) ?

Comment: Does your constraint mean that each box must contain at least $2$ objects?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean each box should contain *at least* 2 objects and not more than 6, the required answer is equal to the coefficient of $\ x^n $ in the following algebraic expression

$\ (x^2 + x^3 +.... + x^6)^k $

You could think of this problem as equivalent to picking the coefficient of $\ x^n $ from the product of the above mentioned $\ k $ algebraic expressions.

Simplifying this, the required answer is equal to the coefficient of $\ x^{n-2k} $ in the expression $\ (1+x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4)^k $